# В чём разница автозагрузчиков php?

Tags: php, autoload

В чем разница автозагрузчиков php `spl_autoload_register`, `spl_autoload()` и `__autoload()`, не могу понять

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**__autoload** - Это метод который срабатывает как магический метод при попытке подключить несуществующий класс.

**spl_autoload()** является просто стандартной готовой реализацией этого метода.

**spl_autoload_register()** - является альтернативой для __autoload(), с помощью этого метода вы можете зарегистрировать функцию которая будет опять-же срабатывать на попытку использования не подключенного класса

*В то время как функция __autoload() также может быть использована для автоматической загрузки классов и интерфейсов, следует отдать предпочтение spl_autoload_register(), потому, что она предоставляет гораздо более гибкую альтернативу, позволяя регистрировать необходимое количество автозагрузчиков, например, для сторонних библиотек. По этой причине использование __autoload() не рекомендуется, а c PHP 7.2.0 объявлено устаревшим.*